# USB smart card reader from a Docker container on a Windows host

Tags: python-3.x, docker, smartcard, pkcs#11, smartcard-reader

I have some python code (with `PyKCS11`) that reads out data from an eID smart card. The eID card is connected to the PC via an USB smart card reader. I'm trying to move this entire setup to docker on a Windows 10 host. The image used is `python:slim-buster`. I was able to install all the necessary drivers + other software on the image. The problem however is with the USB itself, the docker container is unable to fetch the information. I assume it's because docker is unable to detect the USB smart card reader. The same python code, when executed outside the docker container, works fine.

I've tried running docker with `docker run -it --privileged MY_IMAGE_ID`, but with the same issue.

Is it even possible to achieve what I'm trying to do? If so, what am I doing wrong?